# How to calculate the terms of the continued fraction of pi?

Tags: math, pi, continued-fractions

The other day, the Wolfram Blog published an [article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/09/15/from-pi-to-puzzles/) about a thirteen year old boy, Neil Bickford, who computed the first 458 million terms of the simple continued fraction representation of pi, beginning with `[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, ...]`. Bickford described his accomplishment [on his blog](http://nbickford.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/pi/), and even quoted [Bill Gosper's algorithm](http://neilbickford.com/picf.htm), but I haven't been able to work out the algorithm.

One thing I do know is how to convert the decimal representation of pi to a continued fraction, using the method given at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansions_of_.CF.80) on continued fractions. But that requires a decimal representation of pi to a sufficient number of places, and certainly Bickford didn't have millions of digits of pi backing his calculation.

Can someone please explain -- in considerable detail -- the algorithm Bickford used to make his calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually he DID have millions of digits of Pi to start with. He probably used either Mathematica or another pi-program to get the initial digits.

Here's the link to his previous record:

http://neilbickford.com/picf.htm

In this one, he said he used a program called [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-5t/details.html#program) to compute 500 million digits of Pi to start with.

EDIT:

As far as explaining exactly how the algorithm works: I'm not familiar with it myself. It's probably too localized for anyone on SO to be able to answer that.

Comment: Here is Bickford's <a href="http://neilbickford.com/source.txt"source</a>. Maybe the "filename" that he asks you to enter has the digits of pi? I'm not sure. I may have to contact Bickford for assistance.